# How to import IplImage class in opencv android?

Tags: android, opencv, iplimage

How to import and use IplImage class in opencv android?
Or its only support for javacv ??

I try to declare new val by

```
IplImage image = IplImage.create( bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
```

eclipse show that IplImage cannot be resolve to a type.

I tried many ways to import, but i can't find the solution...

Can anyone help ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IplImage is a class of JavaCV, it maps to a mat or senCV class.

I think you must be looking at JavaCV examples and trying to copy them with OpenCV for Android, this pretty much won't work. You're better off looking at OpenCV examples in C++ and trying to implement them using the Android library yourself.